# How to use Sliding Drawer with View Pager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, slidingdrawer, viewpage

I'm trying to make a screen with the view can be change using a View Pager, sliding to left or right, and use a Sliding Drawer to make a toolbar on the bottom, but my code isn't working. Here is the XML. How can I fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:background="#ffffff">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:id="@+id/viewPager" />

<SlidingDrawer
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer"
    android:handle="@+id/slideButton"
    android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewPager">

        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/slideButton"
            android:background="@drawable/closearrow">
        </Button>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFE0"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:text="Option1">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button02"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFE0"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:text="Option2"></Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/Button03"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFFE0"
            android:text="Option3">
        </Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/Button04"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFFE0"
            android:text="Option4">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve it using this:
main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<!-- ViewPager -->
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/viewPager" />
<!-- Footer -->
<include layout="@layout/footer"  /> 
</FrameLayout>
```

footer.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<SlidingDrawer 
    android:layout_width="100dp" 
    android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer" 
    android:handle="@+id/slideHandleButton" 
    android:content="@+id/contentLayout" 
    android:padding="10dip" 
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="right">

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/slideHandleButton" 
        android:background="@drawable/closearrow"></Button>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/contentLayout" 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center|top" 
        android:padding="10dip" 
        android:background="#C0C0C0" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Content"></Button>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn2" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Content"></Button>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/Button03" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Content"></Button>
            </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example using a `ViewpPager`, `PagerTitleStrip` and `DrawerLayout`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
            android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="#33b5e5"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

What I believe isn't working in your example, is that `DrawerLayout` should have 2 children, the first is the view for the main layout, the second is the view for the drawer itself. Notice how my example fits that restriction.